# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /login/

Tags: django

[Everything was working fine now this is the error im getting i cant even login in to admin it gives the same error there too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqX8P.jpg)

Comment: Could you change your question so it is clear what problem you have and what have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Run migrations.
This most probably seems like a migration issue

`python manage.py makemigrations`

then

`python manage.py migrate`